# I need to open files in a format which has no predefined UTI, but I don't own the format. How should I export the UTI?

Tags: macos, cocoa, metadata

The general question: when I don't own a particular file format, but no UTI has been defined for it by someone else, how do I use that file format?

The specific situation: I'm creating a QuickLook plugin for .torrent and .nzb files. (Note: .nzb files are similar to .torrent files, except instead of pointing to a bittorrent tracker, they point to a Usenet server.) I want the plugin to display what data the .nzb/.torrent file points to, what files would be downloaded if they were opened, and any other applicable metadata. To do this, I have to set forth the [Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) for these two filetypes. While .torrent files have a designated UTI of com.bittorrent.torrent, .nzb files do not - the NZB format is [defined by newzbin.com](http://docs.newzbin.com/index.php/Newzbin:NZB_Specs), which doesn't publish its own application (and therefore doesn't define a Mac OS X Uniform Type Identifier for me to use).

The options seem to be:

1. Export and use a UTI in the form of com.example.nzb, where example.com is owned by me. This seems wrong, because I don't own the nzb format.
2. Export and use a UTI in the form of com.newzbin.nzb, where newzbin.com is *not* owned by me. This seems wrong, because I don't own newzbin.com.
3. Do as e.g. [Unison](http://www.panic.com/unison/) (a Mac OS X application) does and ignore UTI entirely, and use `CFBundleTypeExtensions` in my `Info.plist` file. This seems wrong too, because not only is `CFBundleTypeExtensions` deprecated per [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685), but I don't think I can mix use of `CFBundleTypeExtensions` and `LSBundleContentTypes` (if `LSBundleContentTypes` is present, as it must be for me to use the com.bittorrent.torrent UTI, then `CFBundleTypeExtensions` is ignored).

What's the right thing to do in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `mdls` command line utility to find a .nzb file's UTI.

For example performing `mdls` on this QuickTime movie clearly shows its UTI, boxed in red below.
[image: mdls]

Comment: When I do that, I get a dyn.* value for kMDItemContentType - `kMDItemContentType             = "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge8068xc"`. Apple says this is a [Dynamic Type Identifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html). It appears to be unique to the system its generated on, though, so it's not a permanent solution.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll do some research on this.

Comment: It looks like the best idea would be to declare it as `public.nzb`, since you don't own it. Just make sure there are no conflicts with existing applications that open this file.

Comment: @spudwaffle My understanding is that `public` belongs to Apple.

Comment: Maybe you can contact the Newzbin guys and ask if "com.newzbin.nzb" can be the official UTI.

Comment: What solution did you go with?